# How many times can $watchCollection fire for multiple changes to the watched collection?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming, I have this code:

```
var dateRange = {startDate: null, endDate: null};
$scope.$watchCollection(dateRange, function() {} );
dateRange.startDate = new Date();
dateRange.endDate = new Date();
```

How many times "can" the call-back fire? I see it fired once mostly, but I don't know if thats a guarantee. I assume that if a digest cycle were to be triggered between the two assignments, then the callback would get fired twice. If this is a possibility, the only workaround I can think of is: create a NEW daterange object each time either or both the dates change, and then $watch the dateRange variable for changes.
can anyone please suggest any other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional difference between a `$watch` and a `$watchCollection`. One just checks more values than the other during the digest phase.

Javascript runs on a single threaded event loop. You should look that up more but basically -> It means that it runs a task (function) from start to finish, and then checks the call stack to see if a function has been added in the meantime, and if so, runs it, then waits or runs the next one in the stack. Common ways to add functions to the call stack are things like timeouts, intervals, and http requests (with callbacks).
http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/

So just because a variable in javascript changes ie: `$scope.name = "bob"`, doesn't mean a digest cycle is going to run literally after this change. It has to run through whatever function it is on before it goes back to the call stack to look (and run a digest cycle). Whats basically happening in the angular context though, is that angular (behind the scenes) will run a digest cycle automatically every time you use a $scope or service function, etc.

So in your example above, the dateRange variable is being changed WITHIN the same function, so a digest loop will only get thrown once because it doesn't have a chance to in between assignments.

Here is an example of both situations. The first one is when the watched variable gets changed twice in the same function, the second one is where the variable gets changed once in the function (controller), angular runs a digest loops, then it changes again in the async $timeout callback and fires once again.

http://jsfiddle.net/zcqvd0vd/

Comment: I'm trying to understand the possible repercussions of using $watchCollection. W.r.t. my original question, there are two assignment operations being performed on the collection being watched. My assumption is angular will run digests asynchronously, so it could even run between the two assignments. So I don't get the point of using $watchCollection. I want the callback to be called exactly once, so I guess I would be better off doing something like: $scope.$watch(dateRange, function() {}); var newDateRange = {startDate: new Date(), endDate: new Date()}; dateRange = newDateRange;

Comment: I just altered my answer to try and explain this situation. Hope this helps.

Comment: The difference between `$watch` and `$watchCollection` is a bit more than "one just checks more values", but for the purpose of this example it's quite right to assume that.

Comment: Now, back on the main question, here's how the process goes: 1. you set the `dateRange` to be an object 2. you correctly create a `$watchCollection`, this will watch if any of the members change, but the callback function won't be executed now. this is just setting up a watcher. 3. you assign some values to `startDate` and `endDate`, this doesn't trigger the callback and 4. a `$digest` cycle happens at some point, this triggers the callback but notice this happens only after you've set the values 2nd time, this is why it gets triggered only once

Comment: If you really want to trigger the callback twice, you can do this: `$timeout(function(){dateRange.startDate = new Date(); dateRange.endDate = new Date();}, 0)`. This executes the function which sets the dates only on **next $digest cycle**. Even if it has the timeout duration set to 0, that doesn't mean it gets executed instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
    $scope.dateRange = {startDate: null, endDate: null};    
    dateRange.startDate = new Date();
    dateRange.endDate = new Date();
    $scope.$watchCollection('dateRange', function() {} );
```

Answer (score 0):

[From Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection), it says *whenever any of the properties change*, so there should be no limitation on how often it fires and it should work correctly.

However, the first argument to this method is supposed to be a string that is an expression evaluated on scope.

```
$scope.dateRange = dateRange;
$scope.$watchCollection("dateRange", function () {});
```